# how to add multiple boolean to cut from the same object?

Tags: modeling, workflow, archipack-add-on

**Situation**

I have walls in blender that have boolean modifiers to cut window holes or simply an open passage (ArchiPack Pro, Blender 2.9). Works fine.

**Objective**

Now I want to slice the building in a section (to show only the first floor or second floor or basement).

**My Approach**

I've create a builing-sized cube. I pick a solid (in my case the slab/flat roof) and add a boolean modifier selecting the slicing cube. The slab is cut out whereever I put the cube. Nice.

[image: Initally, only the slab is cut. Which is correct. Note the big window on the left]

Now I want to link all other properties with this boolean modifier. Expecting it to cut all solids.
I would press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> on the slab and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select *Modifiers* in order to make links from the slab's modifier to all other solids (including the walls).

**Expectation**

I would expect that all solids in my scene are cut and they do - BUT - also the holes of the windows disapear if I move the cube up (which entails, that the windows disappear. See in the red circle of pictures one and picture two). I would expect them to stay. Is my expectation wrong?

[image: the window disappeared]

**Question**

I do understand that the walls have two boolean modifiers now. For the windows and the cube. How do I activate both modifiers of a wall thus I still can see the windows?

Comment: Are the window boolean objects also modified by the big cube boolean ? (They should not)